# Why does my custom interface always return impossible 0x80040213/VFW_E_NO_CLOCK?

Tags: c++, casting, runtime-error, directshow

I have a transform filter which exposes a custom interface says `IMyInit`. This interface used to be configured some basic setup setting before streaming.

```
DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IMyInit, IUnknown) {
    STDMETHOD HRESULT SetPath(const wchar_t* wcsPath) PURE;
    STDMETHOD HRESULT SetMode(UINT uMode)  PURE;
};
```

Client code like:

```
CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pMyFilter;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MYFILTER, IID_MYFILTER, ..., (void**)&pMyFilter);
// hr is S_OK

CComPtr<IMyInit> pMyInit;
hr = pMyFilter->QueryInterface(IID_IMyInit, (void**)&pMyInit);
// hr is S_OK

hr = pMyInit->SetMode(1);
// hr is 0x80040213/VFW_E_NO_CLOCK
```

In my *CMyFilter::SetMode(UINT uMode)*, there are only **E_POINTER**, **E_INVALIDARG** for parameters checking, and **S_OK** if *uMode* is set. It is not possible to return such error code, **VFW_E_NO_CLOCK**, related to transform filter.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the *IMyInit* interface dispatch in **NonDelegatingQueryInterface**, and it seems like

```
if(riid == IID_IMyInit) {
    return  GetInterface((IMyInit*)this, ppv);
}
```

But! I forgot to let my *CMyFilter* concrete class **inherit** from the *IMyInit* interface. So there is no connection between *IMyInit* and *CMyFilter*.

The **C style casting**, `(IMyInit*)this`, then casts the *ppv* to `CMyFilter`'s some base class, may be the direct show's `CTransformFilter`. The unknown method pointered by `IMyInit::SetMode(UINT)` may require clock to exist. This is why the *VFW_E_NO_CLOCK* will return.